# Crear botones en panel c#

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms, datetime

Intento crear botones en un panel 7 para ser exactos, los obtengo de un array de dateTimes; lo que sucede es que sólo se esta creando un botón con el primer item del array, creo que debería manejar el padding para crear cada boton? pero no sé como resolverlo, tengo este código:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generarSemana(monthCalendar1.BoldedDates);
    }

    private void generarSemana(DateTime[] lista_fechas)
    {
        if (lista_fechas.Length == 7)
        {
            foreach (DateTime fecha in lista_fechas)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Height = 24;
                btn.Width = 100;
                btn.Top = 7;
                btn.Left = 5;
                btn.Text = fecha.ToShortDateString();
                btn.BackColor = Color.Green;


                panel_fechas.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo crear semana.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Efectivamente, estás creando todos los botones en la misma posición (top 7, left 5). Prueba a usar variables (top = i, left = j) y vas modificando esos valores en cada iteración del bucle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice Pikoh en su comentario, estas creando todos los botones en la misma posición, lo que significa que tus botones se apilan unos sobre otros y solo será visible el primero de arriba.
Existen dos o más bien varias soluciones a ese problema. Yo voy a exponer solo dos.

---

Una es variar las coordenadas donde se ubicará cada botón, lo que tiene dos variantes, ya sea que quieras ubicar tus botones en un arreglo vertical (modificas la propiedad `Top`) o en un arreglo horizontal (modificas la propiedad `Left`), el siguiente código crea un arreglo vertical, con los botones espaciados a 7 pixel.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generarSemana(monthCalendar1.BoldedDates);
    }

    private void generarSemana(DateTime[] lista_fechas)
    {
        int topBtn=7;
        if (lista_fechas.Length == 7)
        {
            foreach (DateTime fecha in lista_fechas)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Height = 24;
                btn.Width = 100;
                btn.Top = topBtn;
                btn.Left = 5;
                btn.Text = fecha.ToShortDateString();
                btn.BackColor = Color.Green;

                panel_fechas.Controls.Add(btn);
                //incrementamos la variable topBtn.
                topBtn = btn.Bottom + 7;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo crear semana.");
        }
    }
```

---

La segunda solución muy sencilla y menos trabajosa, es usar en ves de un contenedor de tipo  `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`, usar un contenedor de tipo `System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel` que de manera automática ubicará los controles, sin tener que modificar las propiedades `Top`, `Left` o `Location`; solo tendrías que modificar la propiedad `FlowDirection` del contenedor `FlowLayoutPanel` si quieres que rellene primero en dirección horizontal o vertical.

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo terminé haciendo con el FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: Si claro @nandofer , esa es la mejor variante, de nada estamos aquí para ayudar.